# Compare multiple table and classified the Stauts ID in SQL

Tags: sql

Compare multiple tables (Tabele1, Table2, Table3) and classified the Table1 ID status in New column

If **Table1** ID available in Table2, 'Available in Table2'
If **Table1** ID available in Table3, 'Available in Table3'
Else
Not available

Comment: using left join... please add your trying

Comment: What should happen if the id appears in both table 2 and table 3?

Comment: @jonas Metzler available in Table 2

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the tag for either `sql-server` or `snowflake-cloud-data-platform`. You have two completely different databases tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `LEFT JOIN` together with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT t1.id,
CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL 
 THEN 'Available in Table2' 
WHEN t3.id IS NOT NULL
 THEN 'Available in Table3'
ELSE 'Not available' END AS idStatus
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fu5UDEyd)